# Unexecutable CodeIgniter Code

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i work with CodeIgniter framework my code is not executable or unreadable

what's the problem ?

Errors code #1

```
<?if($user['fraud_status']>0){?>
        <div class="alert-fraud">
            <strong><?php echo lang('users error warning'); ?></strong> <?php echo lang('users error not_fraud'); ?>
        </div>
        <?}else{?>
    <?}?>
```

error code  #2

```
  <?if($limit_dep > 15){?>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <?php echo lang('admin label limit'); ?> <?php echo lang('admin trans deposit'); ?>! <a href="https://blog.blockchain.com/2016/06/15/receive-payments-api-update-address-gap-limits/" target="_blank" class="alert-link"> <?php echo lang('admin label more'); ?></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?}else{?>
  <?}?>

  <?if($limit_sci > 15){?>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <?php echo lang('admin label limit'); ?> SCI! <a href="https://blog.blockchain.com/2016/06/15/receive-payments-api-update-address-gap-limits/" target="_blank" class="alert-link"> <?php echo lang('admin label more'); ?></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?}else{?>
  <?}?>
```

Comment: check value $user['fraud_status']

Comment: maybe you have comment ;short_open_tag in php.ini setup?

Comment: it's already on !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment by @Bluesky suggests, is might be an issue with short open tags, depending on your PHP version. In earlier versions, setting the short_open_tag directive in the php.ini file to "On" might help.

However, this directive was deprecated many years ago and finally removed in PHP 5.4, so if you're using 5.4 or later (which, really, you should - we're now at 7.2!) what you should be doing instead is replacing all instances of `<?` with the long-form `<?php`.

The only exception: The shorthand form for output, `<?=`. That will still work and can't be deactivated by any configuration directive.

So, this is okay for outputting things only:

`<?=$somethingToOutput?>`

These are not:

```
<?if($something) {?>
<?echo $somethingToOutput?>
<?$someVariable = 1?>
```

Write this instead:

```
<?php if($something) { ?>
<?=$somethingToOutput?> or <?php echo $somethingToOutput; ?>
<?php $someVariable = 1; ?>
```

Comment: i do erverythis you say but not work !! 

  <?if($limit_dep > 15){?>  
  "it stop work after > 15 "

pls i want help with this problem !

Comment: As I wrote above: Instead of <?if($limit_dep > 15){?> try to write <?php if($limit_dep > 15){?> and I'm quite confident it will work.